# rake cannot load such file (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

I'm having a strange `rake` error when I try to install, here is what it says

```
$ rake bundle_install
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

When I try to navigate to the directory, i find nothing:

```
$ ls /usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/
specifications/
```

Ruby versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why it's trying to load the wrong version and how I could fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue here, no gems directory available, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to re-install ruby..Hopefully that might solve the problem.Had faced this issue previously.Resolved by reinstalling ruby.

Answer (score 17):

you can try:
    `bundle update rake`

the same issue was resolved here: [Ruby rake loaderror - bundle exec rake not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053451/ruby-rake-loaderror-bundle-exec-rake-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

Look for the gemspec file.

Your version of rake specified at the gemspec file must match the rake version you are using.

Try: `bundle update rake`. This will install a new version of rake. Open your gemspec file and update the rake version.

I had this:
  `spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"`

And I have changed to:
   `spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 11.0"`

run `bundle update rake` again:

`Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 11.3.0 (was 10.5.0)`

After that, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps somebody. I had same error, but with rails, instead of rake.
I have got such error while installing redmine.

```
$ sudo bundle exec rails server webrick -e production

bundler: failed to load command: rails (/usr/local/bin/rails)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/specifications/bin/rails
/usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my solution:

```
$ sudo bundle update rails
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in the latest version.

```
# Rakefile.rb
require 'bugsnag/integrations/rake'
```