# Ruby rake loaderror - bundle exec rake not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm trying to run the command `rake db:migrate` but I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/[name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/[name]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/default/bin/rake (LoadError)
from /Users/[name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/[name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/[name]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Trying `bundle exec rake db:migrate` also gives me the same error.

Is there a way I can solve this issue? (I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.5)

EDIT: The first letter of my [name] in the error is upper case even though in my system, it's lower case.

EDIT [PARTIALLY SOLVED]: So I was using Ruby version 2.2.1 and I was supposed to use 2.1.2. Although this did not fix the `rake` command error, I was trying to run `rails server` which successfully ran after changing my Ruby version.

Comment: The latter command you mention is `bundle exec rake:db migrate`. Do you mean `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or is that an issue?

Comment: yes, that's what i meant. sorry

Comment: @Ol'Reliable Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: yes, and that was successful

Comment: Does `bundle exec gem list` show Rake is installed ?

Comment: @PaulSturgess Yup! rake (10.4.2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If none of the above mentioned comments worked for you, then I suspect you may need to update `rake` gem. Try:

`bundle update rake`

See if that fixes the issue. If not, let me know. I will update the answer.

Comment: can you check if this path really exists or not? `/Users/[name]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/specifications/default/bin/rake`

Comment: There is a similar issue here: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/495
You should try upgrading your `Rubygems` or `bundler` as well. See if that fixes the issue.

Comment: The error log in the question is the entire log. There is nothing else. I will check if the path exists and try upgrading Rubygems and bundler now.

Comment: My path only exists up to: `/Users/[name]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/` .. there is no specifications directory.

Comment: UPDATE: after doing `bundle install rake` I have everything up to and including the `default` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87184/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-ol-reliable).

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/ruby_executable_hooks.rb` error indicates that the error is coming from a Bundler hook. Try to delete the `.bundle` directory in your project root path and see if the error is gone.